# Converting a sequence of pairs to the sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Suppose we have two mutually dependent sequences X and Y with elements

$$x[0],x[1],...,x[n],x[n+1],...$$

and

$$y[0],y[1],...,y[n],y[n+1],...$$

in this

$$x[n] = 1 - x[n-1] + y[n-1]$$
$$y[n] = x[n] + y[n-1]$$

(`x[0]` and `y[0]` have a fixed value and `x[0] = y[0]`)

is there a function `h`, such as

$$x[n] = h(x[n-1])$$?

and find this function if yes.

---

I tried to solve it like this:

(1)

$$x[n] = 1 - x[n-1] + y[n-1]$$
$$y[n] = x[n] + y[n-1]$$

(2)

$$y[n-1] = x[n-1] + y[n-2]$$

(3)

$$x[n] = 1 - x[n-1] + x[n-1] + y[n-2]$$

(4)

$$x[n] = 1 + y[n-2]$$

(5)

```
...?
```

I can't get rid of `y`s in the right side in any way...

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a function $h$ is not possible since, as you note, the sequences depend on one another.  Instead, we can obtain a closed-form solution in terms of $x_0,y_0$. Write the system as

$$z_n=Az_{n-1}+b,$$

$$z_n=\begin{bmatrix}x_n\\y_n\end{bmatrix},A=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\-1&2\end{bmatrix},b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Induction shows

$$z_n=A^nz_0+(I-A)^{-1}(I-A^n)b.$$

Computational software can compute $A^n$. You can also compute it manually if you are familiar with diagonalization ($A$ has eigenvalues of $\varphi$ and $-1/\varphi$, where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio<sup>*</sup>), but the expression ends up being a little messy to write explicitly.

<sup>*<sub>Yours truly</sub></sup>

Comment: what if `x[0] = y[0]`?

Comment: @asianirish The solution Golden_Ratio mentioned is general. If you look carefully, his final formula contains $z_0$, which is defined to be $z_0 = \begin{bmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \end{bmatrix}$. So if $x_0 = y_0$ then I guess that reduces to a single variable of freedom.